# Counting from two tables according to single criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, common-table-expression

I am trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(topic.topic_id) + COUNT(post.post_id)
FROM topic, post WHERE author_id = ?
```

Both tables have column `author_id`.

I get `column reference "author_id" is ambiguous` error.

How can I tell it that `author_id` is present in both tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you *could*, you most probably do not want to join both tables, since that might result in different counts. Explanation in this related answer:
[Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

Two subqueries would be fastest:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(topic_id) FROM topic WHERE author_id = ?)
     + (SELECT COUNT(post_id)  FROM post  WHERE author_id = ?) AS result
```

If `topic_id` and `post_id` are defined `NOT NULL` in their respective tables, you can slightly simplify:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM topic WHERE author_id = ?)
     + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post  WHERE author_id = ?) AS result
```

**If** at least one of both `author_id` columns is *unique*, a **`JOIN`** would work, too, in this case (but slower, and I wouldn't use it):

```
SELECT COUNT(t.topic_id) + COUNT(p.post_id) AS result
FROM   topic t
LEFT   post  p USING (author_id)
WHERE  t.author_id = ?;
```

If you want to enter the value only once, use a [**CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html):

```
WITH x AS (SELECT ? AS author_id)  -- enter value here
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM topic JOIN x USING (author_id))
     + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post  JOIN x USING (author_id)) AS result
```

But be sure to understand how joins work. Read the chapter about [**Joined Tables** in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN).

Comment: Judging by the table names, `author_id` is unlikely to be unique in either of the tables. Anyway, that's a nice technique of using a CTE to avoid specifying the argument twice.